# How to stream different video stream to multiple clients

Tags: c#, sockets, video-streaming, client-server, asyncsocket

looking for some guidance.

i have a server which is required to stream video file data continuously to multiple clients. Each client would have a different video data  being streamed to.

i can stream the data to multiple clients which is fine but not efficient which leads to issue below.

Issue is each client end up buffering for a while at intermittent interval hence the problem arises where we see video pausing until enough data is available to render the video.

So looking for some guidance as to how to make it efficient or tackle the issue.

Possible solution i have thought of:
When a client connects then for each client we start another internal server on server machine and it details to client during handshake. This would require client to make additional connection to the internal server and hence each client would have a 1-1 connection for video streaming.

Is the above approach correct ? if not then any suggestions ?

Note: 
Code is written in C# using sockets and is a desktop application

Comment: `but not efficient` what technologies are you using here, why is it not efficient, can you cope with the band width.

Comment: using TCP protocol. bandwidth isnt a problem. so gar have been testing it locally on my PC